# SetSuspendState не включается монитор

Tags: c++

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <powrprof.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "PowrProf.lib")

int main (void)
{   

    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart = -15*10000000;

    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;

    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);

    SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        
    SetSuspendState(0, 0, 0);
    
    WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);

    HINSTANCE hInst = ::ShellExecute(NULL, "open", ".\\index.html", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    CloseHandle(hTimer);

    return 0;
}
```

Компьютер выходит из спящего режима через 15 секунд, системный блок включается - но дисплей остается черный, не включается. Как решить проблему с дисплеем?